# Using Video in Marketing Cloud Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a very insistent user who is telling me that they can send videos in emails. I advised that gifs or videos without sound can be used but they are telling me full videos are possible. I don't see anything telling me it does and i tried to embed and it doesn't play.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you asked the user to show you how they do it?

Comment: "Can I use videos in MC emails?", "Does MC support responsive design in emails?"... etc. It is important to understand, that MC is only a platform, and it supports whatever HTML/CSS you put into Content Builder. Hence these features are (probably with some few exceptions) agnostic, when it comes to which system you use for email sends. Limitations are more often on the email client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to embed a video in a an email. The problem is - only a number of e-mail apps/clients will actually display embedded video. Email clients that support playing video in the inbox:

- Apple Mail
- Outlook on Mac
- iOS Mail
- Samsung Mail

You can easily look up numerous articles on the Web for more details on how to do it. For example, this website states that there is a poor support: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=video

[image]